# Calling a function in Bourne Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

Is it possible to call a function (defined in a shell script) from Unix console? I have a function like

```
add ()
{
 a=$1
 b=$2
 c=`expr $a + $b`
}
```

This is defined in the script `"my_script.sh"`. How to call this function from command prompt?

Comment: I tried to call this function from command prompt. I don't know the exact command to use as I am new to shell scripting. I tried running the file and then calling this function like "/.my_script.sh < add 1 2"
I know this is a wrong approach but I dont have any clue.So I need guidance.

Comment: Would `source` or using `.profile` work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use arguments you don't apply the redirection operator `<`, which redirects the file given right after the `<` to the standard input of your program. You need to make a call of your function in your script, in order to use the args `$...`, or you can simply load the function in your shell, and use it.

In both cases, the call of your function is to be performed like this:

```
add arg1 arg2
```

If by command line, you must load the contents of your `.sh` file -- your function definitions --, so that you may call them from your shell. In this one case, you file should look like:

```
#! /bin/bash
add () {    
    a=$1
    b=$2
    c=$(expr $a + $b)
    echo $c
}
```

And would use the function in your shell by doing the following:

```
source script.sh
add 100 1000
```

If in your script.sh file, you use:

```
./script.sh arg1 arg2
```

And the contents of the script file would be:

```
#! /bin/bash
add () {

    a=$1
    b=$2
    c=$(expr $a + $b)
    echo $c

}
add $1 $2
```

**Obs**: your syntax was not valid in the function definition: you must embrace an expression in order to assign the result of it's evaluation; the syntax for evaluating an expression may be either `cmd` or $(cmd), with the difference that the first approach allows no nesting calls.

If you have more than one function being defined, you can either set the args for each function call, or simply define your functions, and load them up to your shell with "source script.sh".

Since you've loaded the functions, you need to call them as well as if they've been defined one by one. The args inside the function correspond to the classic "argv[]" parameters in C, they're unique to the function call.

For example, if you wanted to define an add and a sub function, you'd have:

```
#! /bin/bash
add () {
    a=$1
    b=$2
    c=$(expr $a + $b)
    echo $c
}
add $1 $2

sub() {
    a=$1
    b=$2
    c=$(expr $a - $b)
    echo $c
}
sub $3 $4
```

Or whatever argument numbers may fits your application.

Notice, though, that you might lose track of the "semantic" of the vars: this can be caused by the dynamic scope of bash scripting, which shadows your variable definitions each time a call is performed.

A straightforward example of this is a for loop. Consider the add function defined as follows:

```
add () {
    let i=$1 + $2
}
```

And the for loop being performed as:

```
for (( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )); do
    echo $i
    add i 5
    echo $i
done
```

The output is:

```
0
5
6
11
```

since the variable "i" has been modified, during the for loop, not only by the "i++", but by the function "add", that has "i" being used in its scope.

Comment: what if the script file has more than one function?
    #! /bin/bash

    add () {

    a=$1
    b=$2
    c=$(expr $a + $b)
    echo $c

    }

    add $1 $2
    
    sub() {

    a=$1
    b=$2
    c=$(expr $a - $b)
    echo $c

    }

    sub $1 $2

Comment: @NathanPk then you either set the args for each function call, or simply define your functions, and load them up to your shell with "source script.sh". Since you've loaded the functions, you need to call them as well as if they've been defined one by one. The args inside the function correspond to the classic argv parameters in C, they're unique to the function call.

Comment: ... In the case you've pointed, you'd have: #! /bin/bash add () { a=$1 b=$2 c=$(expr $a + $b) echo $c } add $1 $2 sub() { a=$1 b=$2 c=$(expr $a - $b) echo $c } sub $3 $4 (or whatever may fits your application). Notice, though, that you might've asked this because amidst the functions, you've lost the "semantic" of the vars: this might be caused by the dynamic scope of bash scripting, which shadows your variable definitions each time a call is performed.

Comment: when I tried sourcing the above script, I am getting an error message like "Badly placed ()'s". Any reason for this error? What is wrong with parenthesis?

Comment: The error is given to the call of the functions "add" and "sub" without parameters. If you remove the calls "add $1 $2" and "sub $1 $2" you'll be able to run the functions in your shell, after loading. I've added a resumed explanation on what I've pointed about dynamic scoping, if you may get interested.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! The problem did not get resolved even after removing the calls.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
    add()
    {
    a=$1
    b=$2
    c=`expr $a + $b`
    echo $c
    }

I tried sourcing this "source my_script.sh" and it returns error

Comment: You need to embrace an expression with either `\`expression\`` or `$(expression)`, in order to attribute its result to a variable. In this case, you need: `#!/bin/sh add() { a=$1 b=$2 c=$(expr $a + $b) echo $c }`. Regards!

Comment: Is this working for you? I am getting the same error result for my corrected version.

Comment: I guess you're saving the script in a single line. If you're doing so, you need to add semicolons to the syntax, so that the script can be parsed properly; try doing this: `add() { a=$1 b=$2 c=$(expr $a + $b); echo $c; }; add $1 $2`. And execute it as `./script.sh 20 30`.

Comment: the script works for command "./script.sh 20 30" . but source script.sh is not working.

Comment: To source the script you must remove the function call, as I've pointed in the example. If you want to source the script, have this in your script.sh file: `add() { a=$1 b=$2 c=$(expr $a + $b); echo $c; }`, and then, in your shell, `source script.sh`, and `add 20 20`.

Comment: Yes I used the same format. Problem is because of the parenthesis "()" I searched in Google for this error but I dint get any proper way to resolve this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help any further; all the code I've posted has been tested, and they do work fine. I'm really out of ideas on why such errors are happening during your execution.

Comment: note that `source` is bash-specific -- for /bin/sh use the `.` command

Comment: If the "script" in question is intended to be a library of shell functions, rather than a standalone executable, it's clearer to a reader who knows that shebangs are used during the execution process _not_ to use a shebang at all, unless your editor requires it. (Similarly -- a `.sh` extension should be used if this is a POSIX sh shell library, a `.bash` extension for a bash library, no extension at all for an executable).